# how to push in array which is inside of services and push in object of an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

```
 <pre lang="HTML">
 <ul>
 <li data-ng-repeat="q in QuizObj">
 <fieldset><legend>All Quizes </legend>
     <h1>{{q.Quiz  }}</h1>
     <h3>options</h3>
     <h3>answer</h3>
        &lt;input type="radio" />{{q.options[1]}}
        &lt;input type="radio" />{{q.options[2]}}
        &lt;input type="radio" />{{q.options[3]}}
        &lt;input type="radio" />{{q.options[4]}}
        <h4>Answer</h4>
        &lt;input type="radio" />{{q.answer}}
  </fieldset>
        </li>
    </ul>
 &lt;input type="text" ng-model="ans">
    &lt;input type="text" ng-model="Question" >

    &lt;input type="text" ng-model="type">
    &lt;input type="button" data-ng-click="addQuiz()">
```

**and this is js angular code**

```
angular.module('quizApp',[])
.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope,crudService){

$scope.name="this";
        alert(JSON.stringify(crudService.quiz));
        $scope.QuizObj= crudService.quiz;
    })
    .service('crudService',function(){
        this.quiz=[
            {
                Quiz: "what is the C#",
                options: {  1: 'P-lang',
                            2:'h-lang',
                            3: 'A-lang',
                            4: 'nothing'
                        },
                type: 'radio',
                answer: 1
            },
            {
                Quiz: "what is the J#",
                options: {  1: 'P-lang',
                    2:'h-lang',
                    3: 'A-lang',
                    4: 'nothing'
                },
                type: 'radio',
                answer: 1
            },
            {
                Quiz: "what is the VB",
                options: {  1: 'PL',
                    2:'hL',
                    3: 'AL',
                    4: 'nothing'
                },
                type: 'radio',
                answer: 1
            }
        ]

    })
```

i have a some problem
i want to add question into quiz while quiz object is in service how to add this i am doing 
this

```
   $scope.addQuiz= function($scope){
                crudService.quiz.push({
                    Quiz: $scope.Question,
                    type: $scope.type,
                    answer: $scope.ans
                })

        }
```

but showing me an error
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'Question' of undefined**
how to push in services's object (quiz). ??
how to push in option which is another object in Quiz object. ??
plus i want to allow user to add type of answer 
types are
1: true\false  (checkbox)
2: Mulitiple answer (checkbox)
3. single answer (radio)
how to do this ?? although i have added a opition in quiz but don't know how to do this and create its layout??

Comment: can you create a fiddle for it ?

Answer (score 1):

You are obviously not passing the `$scope` argument when calling your `addQuiz()` function. Since `$scope` is in the JS context of the `addQuiz` function, you can omit it altogether:

```
$scope.addQuiz = function () {
    crudService.quiz.push({
        Quiz: $scope.Question,
        type: $scope.type,
        answer: $scope.ans
    });
};
```

Comment: @MohammadFaizankhan: Thank you for the suggestion ! I will rea...wait...I did read the question before I answered (silly me, but I did). Maybe you cared to share a more informative comment...